# How to download a file from the command line? via ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ssh

I want to download files from a remote server to my local drive, and do it from the command line. I also want to be able to do this over SSH. How can I do this?

Note: the remote server is Ubuntu, the local is Mac OS X

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `scp`-command, it runs on top of SSH. Example:

```
scp username@remote.host:/path/to/file localfile
```

It also works another way round

```
scp localfile username@host:/path/remotefile
```

Username, path, and filename can be omitted (but not the `:` !).

As Iain said, SFTP works also, but I tend to favor `scp` for its `cp`-like usage.

Comment: Less common I'm sure, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I think scp also works remote-to-remote, if you really need to:  `scp username@remote1:/path/to/file username@remote2:/path/to/file`

Comment: can you copy directories?

Comment: figured it out... -r recursively copies directories too

Comment: I recommend adding the `-p` option when copying files or folders with `scp`.  It copies over the file attributes too (timestamps and flags).  I find I want `-p` more often than I don't want it!

Comment: You can also remote-to-remote routed through the localhost using the `-3` flag: `scp -3 jeff@firsthost.com:/files/file1.zip brad@secondhost.com:/archives` This is useful if you need to use a private key for access to both servers only found on localhost: `scp -3i /local/path/to/.ssh/private_key dan@host1:/path/to/file.txt miri@host2:/path/to/upload/dir/` The progress bar is disabled for -3

Comment: On mac terminal to linux box, my local path is being interpreted as a server path. `scp java-named-objects.yml ~/Documents/sap` Getting `cp: cannot create regular file `/ngs/app/gsmt/Documents/sap': No such file or directory`

Comment: **I keep getting `set times: Input/output error`** when I try to run `scp -r -p`... I think I'll be using a different tool...

Comment: Decided to use `7z`, archive the folder up with `7z a -r folder.7z folder/*`, and then download with `scp`.

Answer (score 3):

I use SFTP for this. It's command line and uses the same security as SSH.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `rsync` for it. It can work over SSH.

Comment: `rsync -avvP` is my favourite for files and/or folders, but there is one drawback: it needs to be installed on the remote machine.

Comment: If you are having trouble connecting, you may need to pass `-e ssh` to tell rsync to connect over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `scp` or SFTP you can use `tar` over SSH:

```
tar cf - . | ssh otherhost "cd /mydir; tar xvf -"
```

This one is also good if you have sparse files which otherwise will "explode".